# Tkinter.Scale right click

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-scale

I have this program where I want the user to be able to right click a tkinter Scale widget in order to set it's value with a popup. There is no problem with the popup itself, but when I right-click it, it does what is intended and then does as if I clicked the widget directly, so sets its value to whatever value I clicked.
The relevant code looks something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

Scale = tk.Scale(window, from_=100, to=0, command=fun)
slider.grid(column=0, row=2)
slider.bind("<Button-2>", fun_popup)
```

Does anyone know a way I could get the right click event on the Scale without triggering the command?